# Unidentified word or construction

Tags: meaning, expressions, idioms, parts-of-speech

There is a puzzling sequence of words in the following text (bold type).

> We live in a society in which
> money is needed to survive. Unfortunately, many people work in no-end jobs just to have some money to get by. Petey's job is simple and **pasts his time well**, whether he likes it or not. Stanley, once a pianist, left his job to live by the sea. For what ever reason Stanley left, he ran away. Like Stanley, many people leave jobs behind to find something else or to escape working all together.

I first thought of a verb unknown to me, the verb "*to past*" used in the third person singular of the present; however, there is no such verb in the usual dictionaries.

[Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/past), [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/past), [OALD](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/past_1?q=past), [lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/past)

The SOED gives no further clue, except for the mention of an obsolete past participle of the verb "to pass", and anyway, this possibility, if one accounts for the ending s as a typing error, seems to be no solution, that being so in view of the resulting syntax and meaning.

There is an apparent solution if the form "pasts" is reckoned with as the preposition (again, final s would be an error), but then "well" at the end makes for a bizarre expression, while "well past his time" is difficult to understand (no interpretation seems satisfactory to me).

Would someone see a way out of this conundrum?

Comment: error for *passes.*

Comment: @Xanne I am not familiar with this meaning of the verb "to pass" ("the job passes the time"?).  Is a dictionary reference available to you?

Comment: The source you copied is a poor one, containing a number of mistakes. Just ignore it.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the question is based on a misprint, OCR error, or poor transcription.

Answer (score 3):

This is a quote from an essay on Harold Pinter's The Birthday Party. Far be it from me to question the author's grammar, but I would interpret the above as "Petey's job is simple and **passes** his time well, whether he likes it or not". That is to say, his job occupies his time well.

See definition 5a of the transitive verb section of [M-W definition](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pass) of "to pass".

Comment: Do you have a dictionary reference for this meaning of "to pass" ?

Comment: This is not from Pinter's *The Birthday Party* but from an exegesis concerning this play : [THE BIRTHDAY PARTY - Parkway Schools](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=In+Stanley%27s+case%2C+he+is+running+from+betrayal+and+the+lack+of+acceptance.)

Comment: Your link doesn’t work.

Comment: Thanks LPH, you've restored my faith in Harold Pinter's grammar.

Comment: Note also the error in "*Unfortunately, many people work in no-end jobs*", which should be either "no end of jobs" or "dead-end jobs".

Comment: Harold Pinter is known for depicting characters who make non-standard vernacular uses of English. This might be an intentional malapropism, or it could be an error of the commentator.